# Class not mapped in hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle10g, hibernate-mapping

The problem is fairly simple it seems but i am unable to pin point exactly what is the issue. So here goes the issue:

What i want is my DTO class be mapped to a table which is in `ORACLE DB`.

Below is one snap of my class

**P.S: My table has only one column which is as per requirement and is primary key which will any time contain `sysdate`. Bizarre but it is what it is**

`myDTOClass.java`

```
package com.cisco.dto;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table_in_oracle_db")
public class myDTOClass{

    @Id
    @Column(name ="LASTRUNDATE")
    private Date lastRunDate;

    public Date getLastRunDate() {
        return lastRunDate;
    }

    public void setLastRunDate(Date lastRunDate) {
        this.lastRunDate = lastRunDate;
    }
}
```

As you can see i have used hibernate annotations with `@entity` and i also have `@Id`, so this is not an issue.

Rest assured my database has the mentioned table with the table name spelled in absolute correctness in my class.

Now i thought my `hibernate.cfg.xml` might have issues with connection. But my all other tables and their respectiv `DTO` classes are running as smooth as butter.

Below is the `hibernate.cfg.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        </property>

        <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<host_name>)(PORT=1234))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=*SID*)(Server=Dedicated)))
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            *my_user_name*
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            *my_password*
        </property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">
            1
        </property>

        <property name="show_sql">
            true
        </property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">
            true
        </property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">
            update
        </property>

        <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
        <!--<mapping class="com.cisco.learnhibernate.dto.UserDetails" />-->

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The error i am getting is :
 `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: myDTOClass is not mapped` when i try to call the below block:

```
Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.createQuery("delete from myDTOClass").executeUpdate();

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: "The problem is fairly simple" <- Then you should probably tell us what that problem is. because you so far have only described what you are trying to do but not where you are stuck / what problem occurs.

Comment: My Bad. forgot to add the error. Edited just now

Comment: Have you got proper mapping for `myDTOClass` in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` configuration? Like: `<mapping class="com.package. myDTOClass"/>`

Comment: I am using hibernate annotations. So there is no need of mapping to be done.

Answer (score 1):

you have done everything well. but you forgot to add the bean class to configuration.before using the bean class you should configure it and create a schema for it in the DB.

Since you are using annotations use this.

```
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();//this will configure the hibernate cfg.xml
   cfg.addAnnotatedClass(myDTOClass.class);//this will create schemas in the DB
Session session=cfg.buildSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tr=session.beginTransaction();
session.createQuery("delete from myDTOClass").executeUpdate();
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```